# Will uneven speed be rounded up or down?

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e, battle-map

When using the sneak action you can move up to half your speed. If I play a goblin with 25 base speed what would be half the speed? Will 12.5 be rounded up to 15 or down to 10? Since 2.5 is difficult to use in a grid map.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Always round down (unless told not to); half your speed is 10

The [General Rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) state:

> **Rounding**
>
> You may need to calculate a fraction of a value, like halving damage. Always round down unless otherwise specified. For example, if a spell deals 7 damage and a creature takes half damage from it, that creature takes 3 damage.

Comment: This doesn't directly address, if 12.5 speed should be rounded down to 12 or down to 10. Is there anything in the rules about rounding movement on grid?

Comment: @Waki I couldn't find anything. But even if it rounded to 12, you couldn't move 3 squares AKA *15* feet

Answer (score 19):

It would round down to 10, because that obeys the rule to move up to, but not beyond, half your speed.

It can't be rounded up to 15, because that would be **more than** half your speed, breaking the rule that you can move only **up to** half your speed.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic I see what you mean, but I don't think that quite reaches the finish line. Half of 25 rounded up would be 13. With an answer of 13, you would still have to answer the question of how to use the partial square of movement when using a grid. Both rounding up and rounding down would still needs the above reasoning to resolve on a grid.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense to me! Comment removed

Comment: Thanks for dropping by, is the grid point you make in the comment due to PF 2e being grid centric? (Don't have that game)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Given the context of Grid squares and 5 foot intervals for grid movement, rounding up or down also occurs in intervals of 5, as you had mentioned a movement of 12 or 13 would both be invalid for movement on a grid system.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, it is very grid centric. Not quite as openly as DnD-4e was, where your speed was provided in squares instead of in feet, but still. For example, the Difficult Terrain rules mention squares first, and feet only in parenthesis.